# How to format date in flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm using Flex+java+Mysql.. in that i want to insert the datetime taking from flex to mysql in that i got date String like this

```
 Sat Aug 4 12:05:00 GMT+0530 2012
```

how to convert `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z` 
this formate so please give code in `java` or `flex`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flex API Given DateFile class, in that we have two methods dateTOString(), stringTODate().

```
DateField.dateToString(dateInput.selectedDate,"DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Please Refere Below Doc.
[DateField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html)

Answer (score 1):

DateField.dateToString(addr1.selectedDate,"YYYY-MM-DD").toString();